# How to get a solid color/no picture theme in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8

The three default themes in Windows 8 show pictures of flowers or earth. How do I get a theme with just a solid color?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create your own theme by changing the desktop wallpaper and window color,

1. First choose solid color and select what color you want, then save changes, your new unsaved theme will now show up. If you want a custom Solid color click the "more" icon, configure your custom color then hit the "add to custom colors" button, then ok.
2. Change window color and or "advanced appearance settings"  for that theme if you desire.
3. Right click on the new unsaved theme Icon and choose to "save theme", give it a name.

[image]

.

[image]

.

[image]

.

[image]

.
[image]